# Using different program office extension

Tags: ms-office, office-addins

I have a program that can access a database with a whole bunch of articles.

Due to copyright, I can't access the database straight from my program, but I have a different program that can access it, and it's legitimate to copy small bits from the articles.

Because my friends and I quote a lot from these articles, I thought it would be useful if we could find an add-in for Word that will copy the requested part from an article.

Is there any add-in for Word that would let me use the program that I mentioned above so that I can access the database from within Word?

I would like to program this add-in myself, if possible.

Comment: @SunnyJuneja I can't access it without using the program anyway.

Comment: Does that programm which can access the database has an API?

Comment: @MeNoMore I don't think so. is there a way to use it without a API?

Answer (score 2):

Without further information about which operating system, and version of Word you are using, I can offer only a general outline.

1) It seems to me that you want to make a Word macro using Word Basic, or Visual Basic.
2) When you want to call your program which is external to Word, you need to use the shell command as outlined here from [Microsoft's webpage](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/79696).

I hope that helps you get started writing your macro!

CHEERS

Comment: If it matters, I well first aim to word 2010, and later own might expand to earlier versions. can I record actions? (pressing buttens and so?)

Answer (score 0):

Well its a wrokaround but you can use an automation tool which can run a sequence of actions on a given GUI like [Winrunner](http://www.loadtest.com.au/Technology/winrunner.htm) or [TestQuest](http://www.bsquare.com/products/testquest-automated-testing-platform) to semulate the usage of the program, i assume these tools can get an input from a given xml or text file and log outputs in log text file.

If you have the output in a text file you will be able to parse the file using any programmign language and get the information you need and write it to eord or whatever format using OLE objects.